# Error C2679: бинарный "<<": не найден оператор, принимающий правый операнд типа "std::_Tree_iterator<_Mytree>"

Tags: c++

Задача поместить экземпляры производного класса в контейнер multimap и вывести содержание контейнера в консоль. Проблема в выводе содержимого контейнера через find.

```
C++
#include "medycnyy zaklad.h"
#include "apteka.h"
#include "likarnya.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <fstream> 
#include <iomanip>


//using namespace std;
void main ()
{   
    //Роота з класом MedycnyyZaklad
    // Створення екземпляру (з ім’ям medycnyyzaklad) класу MedycnyyZaklad, використовується конструктор за умовчанням - MedycnyyZaklad();
    class MedycnyyZaklad medycnyyzaklad = MedycnyyZaklad();
    // Заповнення членів екземпляру класу з типом доступу privat:
    medycnyyzaklad.setName("Ateka");
    medycnyyzaklad.setCity("Poltava");
    medycnyyzaklad.setStreet("Street");
    medycnyyzaklad.setHouse(1);

    //Друк екземплярів класу MedycnyyZaklad
    cout<<"Class  MedycnyyZaklad"<<endl;
    medycnyyzaklad.Show();  //Друк назву закладу, міста, вулиці та номеру будинку


    // Створити екземпляру класу MedycnyyZaklad, з конструктором з заповненням 
    class MedycnyyZaklad medycnyyzaklad1 = MedycnyyZaklad("Apteka1","Poltava1","Street1");
    cout<<endl<<"Class medycnyyzaklad1:"<<endl;
    medycnyyzaklad1.ShowName(); //Роздрукувати назву закладу та місто


    // Створити новий екземпляр класу - Конструктор копіювання
    class MedycnyyZaklad medycnyyzaklad2 = medycnyyzaklad1;
    medycnyyzaklad2.setName("Apteka2");
    cout<<endl<<"Class medycnyyzaklad2:"<<endl;
    medycnyyzaklad2.ShowName(); //Роздрукувати назву закладу та місто

    //Робота з класом Apteka
    //Створення екземпляоу класу apteka1 використовуючи конструктор з параметром
    cout<<endl<<"Class apteka1:"<<endl;
    class Apteka apteka1=Apteka('R',"Private","Apteka number 1","Poltava","Street",1);
    //Ввивід вмісту членів класу
    cout<< "The nature of the activity-"<<apteka1.getActivities()<<endl<<"Ownership-"<<apteka1.getOwnership()<<endl;
    apteka1.Show(); //Друк назву закладу, міста, вулиці та номеру будин, наслідування методу class MedycnyyZaklad

    //Створення екземпляоу класу apteka2 використовуючи конструктор копіювання
    class Apteka apteka2=apteka1;
    cout  << endl  << "Class apteka2: " << endl; 
    apteka2.Show(); //Друк назву закладу, міста, вулиці та номеру будинку
    //Ввиводимо вміст членів класу
    cout<< "The nature of the activity-"<<apteka2.getActivities()<<endl<<"Ownership-"<<apteka2.getOwnership()<<endl;
    apteka2.ShowApteka();

    //Створення екземпляру класу apteka3 використовуючи конструктор за умовчанням, без заповнення
    cout  << endl  << "Class apteka3: " << endl;
    class Apteka apteka3=Apteka(); //Створити екземпляо класу
    cout   << "Instance of the class - garbage" << endl; 
    apteka3.Show();




    multimap<int, Apteka> Database;   
    Database.insert(make_pair(1,apteka1));
    Database.insert(make_pair(2,apteka2));


    cout<<Database.find(2);

    system("pause");
    return ;
}
```

Сам класс

```
C++
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
//Class Likarnya - похідний
class Likarnya : public MedycnyyZaklad
{
    //За умовчанням privat:
    string strTOrganization;    //Тип організації
    string strTSpecialization; //Тип спеціалізації
    int iNMatches;  //Кількість відділень
    int iNBeds; //Кількість ліжок
public:
    //Конструктор за умовчанням
    Likarnya(){};
    //Перевірка правильності введення типу організації та специалізації
    bool isValidAllLikarnya(char*); 
    //Конструктор опису
    Likarnya (char *chTOrganization,char *chTSpecialization, int iNMatchesR, int iNBedsR);
    //Конструктор копіювання
    Likarnya(const Likarnya & Likarnya, const MedycnyyZaklad & other) : MedycnyyZaklad(other)
    {
        setTOrganization((char*)Likarnya.strTOrganization.c_str());
        setTSpecialization((char*)Likarnya.strTSpecialization.c_str());
        setNMatches(Likarnya.iNMatches);
        setNBeds(Likarnya.iNBeds);
    };
    //Віртуальний деструктор
    virtual~Likarnya(){};
    //Змінити елементи екземпляру класу
    void setTOrganization(char *chTOrganization);// {this-> strTOrganization=chTOrganization;}; //Змінити тип організації
    void setTSpecialization(char *chTSpecialization);// {this->strTSpecialization=chTSpecialization;};  //Змінити тип спеціалізації
    void setNMatches(int iNMatchesR) {this->iNMatches=iNMatchesR;}; //Змінити кількість відділень
    void setNBeds (int iNBedsR) {this->iNBeds=iNBedsR;}; //Змінити кількість ліжок
    //Отримати екземпляри класу
    string getTOrganization() const {return strTOrganization;}  //Отримати тип організації
    string getTSpecialization() const {return strTSpecialization;}  //Отримати тип спеціалізації
    int getNMatches() const {return iNMatches;} //Отримати кількість відділень 
    int getNbeds() const {return iNBeds;} //Отримати кількість ліжок
    //Друк інформації про лікарню
    void ShowLikarnya(){
        cout<<getMedycnyyZaklad()<<" "<< getTOrganization()<<" "<<getTSpecialization()<<" "<<getNMatches()<<" "<<getNbeds()<<endl;}
    //Опис методів похідного класу
    //Конструктор опису
    Likarnya::Likarnya(char *chTOrganization, char *chTSpecialization, int iNMatchesR, int iNBedsR, char *chName, char *chCity, char *chStreet, int iHouseR) : MedycnyyZaklad(chName, chCity, chStreet, iHouseR)
    //Типи змінних співпадають з типами у базовому класі
    {
         setTOrganization(chTOrganization);
         setTSpecialization(chTSpecialization);
         setNMatches(iNMatchesR);
         setNBeds(iNBedsR);
    }
    };
    //Члени-функції класу (методи)
    //Перевірка форми типу організації та специалізації 
bool Likarnya::isValidAllLikarnya(char* word)
{
    char simvol=word[0];
    if( simvol>=65 && simvol<=104  ||  simvol>=192 && simvol<=223 ) return true;
    else return false;
}
//Опис методів для запису даних до закритих членів класу
//Ввести тип організації
void Likarnya::setTOrganization(char*Name5)
{
    bool b=isValidAllLikarnya(Name5);
 try 
  {
   if(b) this->strTOrganization=Name5;  //Запис значення strTOrganization до екземпляру класу
   else  throw b;           //Ловимо виключення
  }
 catch(bool b)              //Ловимо виключення  
  { 
     cout << "Not valid TOrganization!" << Name5 << endl;
  }
}
//Ввести тип специалізації
void Likarnya::setTSpecialization(char*Name6)
{
    bool b=isValidAllLikarnya(Name6);
 try 
  {
   if(b) this->strTSpecialization=Name6;    //Запис значення strTSpecialization до екземпляру класу
   else  throw b;           //Ловимо виключення
  }
 catch(bool b)              //Ловимо виключення  
  { 
     cout << "Not valid TSpecialization!" << Name6 << endl;
  }
}
```

Ругается на

```
C++
  multimap<int, Apteka> Database;   
    Database.insert(make_pair(1,apteka1));
    Database.insert(make_pair(2,apteka2));


    cout<<Database.find(2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cout<<Database.find(2)->first;
```

`.find()` возвращает **итератор**, и как его выводить - `cout` не знает. И вообще, надо проверить, что что-то таки найдено... Примерно так -

```
auto it = Database.find(2);
if (it != Database.end())
{
    cout<< it->first;   // Ключ
    cout<< it->second;  // Значение
    ...
```

Понятно, что если ключ или значение - "нестандартного" типа, то для них тоже надо писать свою перегрузку оператора вывода `<<`.

Comment: Теперь такая ошибка: error C2679: бинарный "<<": не найден оператор, принимающий правый операнд типа "Apteka" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)

Comment: Ну так напишите соответствующую перегрузку оператора, в чем проблема?...